# Removing border that appears in map exported with arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF?

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, borders

I am exporting the current mxd map with all the layers that appear but it saves it with a framework around it. How can I get rid of it? It appears as well when I export to other formats.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]  
df.scale = 1250000 
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, "C:/Users/DickVater/Documents/ArcGIS/IASTE internship/Final map/year/" + name_save + ".pdf")
```

[image: MXD exported to JPEG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layout mode click on the data frame to select it. Then right-click, and choose `Properties`.

[image]

Click the `Frame` tab and choose `<None>` for `Border`.

[image]